# Some Apache .service files are missing

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2

After unmasking my Apache Server it deleted some essential .service and .conf files. Is there a way I can reinstall only the missing packages without changing my local .conf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After unmasking my Apache Server it deleted some essential .service and .conf files.

Restore them from a backup.

- "Apache" and "service" only shows me 1 result on our systems:

  ```
  $ locate .service | grep http       
  $ locate .service | grep apache
  /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
  /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/apache2-systemd.conf
  ```

  Contents:

  ```
  $ /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d$ more apache2-systemd.conf
  [Service]
  Type=forking
  RemainAfterExit=no
  ```

Can you edit into the question a list of file names you removed?  Maybe `history` can help identify them. Or maybe you get an error that a service or conf is missing.

Regarding .conf: most of them are personal so can not be recreated by the system and you really need to restore them from a backup.

Comment: I managed to back it up, it's working now, thanks!